# itextSharp rename duplicate file name

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, itext

I am creating a PDF file using iTextSharp and the file name is the date of the current day. I want that for same file name it should give them number such as 08-08-2018(1),  08-08-2018(2) and so on. Below is my code. Please assist me.

```
string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 25f, 25f, 30f, 160f);
//PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("c://sample.pdf", FileMode.Create));
string pdfFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\InvoicesSummary\";
PdfWriter writer = PdfAWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(pdfFilePath + "/" + filename + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
document.Open();
```

Comment: So your problem is checking how many files match a specific pattern in a folder to name the file you are going to create pattern(count_of_files_plus_one). I wonder how this relates to wpf or itext

Comment: tusi saray ni maa di budi ay kam az kam flag tay ni karyeo jadon answer dean da chut ich zor nahi gando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `File.Exists` method to check whether a file with the same name already exists. Something like this:

```
string pdfFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\InvoicesSummary\";
string baseFilename = pdfFilePath + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string filename = baseFilename;
int n = 1;
while (System.IO.File.Exists(filename + ".pdf"))
    filename = baseFilename + "(" + n++ + ")";

Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 25f, 25f, 30f, 160f);
PdfWriter writer = PdfAWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(filename + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
document.Open();
```

Comment: You need to make a `baseFilename` variable, and change the fifth line to `filename = baseFilename + ...`; otherwise you're going to get "08-08-2018(1)(2)(3).pdf".

Comment: @AdamV you are right. It is causing problem which you have mentioned.

Comment: @AdamV: Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: You need to add a `.ToString()` to be able to concatenate the `"("` with the integer variable.

Comment: @bradbury9: No, I don't.